# How do I add to an existing Knockout JS mapped object?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a JSON data from an api that looks like this:

```
var dataTotalInit = { dataTotal: [{ Cost: 0, Quantity: 0, Security: "" }] };
var mappingResult = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataTotalInit, {}, self);
```

Later when I get my data from a buttonClick, I want to add to my JSON.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AnotherObject(),function(item) {
     self.dataTotal.push({Cost:item.Cost(),Quantity:item.Quantity(),Security:item.Security()});
});
```

When I step thru my code, it does add the values to dataTotal but the data isn't observable and so my view doesn't update.  Please help thanks

Comment: Make `dataTotal` an observable array?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var dataTotalInit = ko.observableArray();
```

There's no need to pre-populate the array, but you could do so:

```
var dataTotalInit = ko.observableArray([[{ Cost: 0, Quantity: 0, Security: "" }]);
```

Then, as you have in your example, push items into the observableArray:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AnotherObject(),function(item) {
     self.dataTotal.push({Cost:item.Cost(),Quantity:item.Quantity(),Security:item.Security()});
});
```

More info:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I need to initialize and map the dataTotal.  In my view I have input boxes that data-bind them.  Is there a way to do this with mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make all properties of a new object observable too:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AnotherObject(),function(item) {
    self.dataTotal.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({Cost:item.Cost(),Quantity:item.Quantity(),Security:item.Security()}));
});
```